# VBA expression evaluation order

Tags: vba, expression

I wanted to find out in which order the VBA evaluates the terms inside the expression.

I have read the document about [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/operator-precedence) and thought it will simply evaluate from left to right if the terms are all operated with "+".
However I get these strange results.

```
Option Explicit
Dim x
Sub test()
    Debug.Print CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") _
        .GetFileVersion(Application.Path & "\Excel.exe") ' 16.0.12624.20086
    x = 0: Debug.Print inc_x + x      '(a) 2
    x = 0: debug_print inc_x + x      '(b) 2
    x = 0: Debug.Print x + inc_x      '(c) 2 <=== ?
    x = 0: debug_print x + inc_x      '(d) 2 <=== ?
    x = 0: Debug.Print inc_x + 0 + x  '(e) 2
    x = 0: debug_print inc_x + 0 + x  '(f) 2
    x = 0: Debug.Print 0 + x + inc_x  '(g) 2 <=== ?
    x = 0: debug_print 0 + x + inc_x  '(h) 1 <=== ???
End Sub

Function inc_x()
    x = x + 1
    inc_x = x
End Function

Function debug_print(msg)
    Debug.Print msg
End Function
```

I thought (c), (d), and (g) should print 1 but they print 2.
And it gets even weirder when you look at (h) which is the only one printing 1.

Can someone explain what is happening ?

**added more patterns**

I added (i),(j),(k),(l),(m), and (n) which also shows interesting patterns.
@SJR also taught me that specifying the type of x as Long will change the result of (d).

```
Option Explicit
Dim x 'As Long 'specifying the type will change the result of (d)
Sub test()
    Debug.Print CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") _
        .GetFileVersion(Application.Path & "\Excel.exe")  ' 16.0.12624.20086
    x = 0: Debug.Print inc_x + x      '(a) 2
    x = 0: debug_print inc_x + x      '(b) 2
    x = 0: Debug.Print x + inc_x      '(c) 2 <=== ?
    x = 0: debug_print x + inc_x      '(d) 2 <=== ? (This becomes 1 when x is Long)
    x = 0: Debug.Print inc_x + 0 + x  '(e) 2
    x = 0: debug_print inc_x + 0 + x  '(f) 2
    x = 0: Debug.Print 0 + x + inc_x  '(g) 2 <=== ?
    x = 0: debug_print 0 + x + inc_x  '(h) 1 <=== ???
    x = 0: Debug.Print 100 * inc_x + 10 * x + 1 * inc_x '(i) 122
    x = 0: debug_print 100 * inc_x + 10 * x + 1 * inc_x '(j) 112
    x = 0: Debug.Print 1000 * x + 100 * inc_x + 10 * x + 1 * inc_x '(k)     2122
    x = 0: debug_print 1000 * x + 100 * inc_x + 10 * x + 1 * inc_x '(l)     112
    x = 0: Debug.Print 10000 * inc_x + 1000 * x + 100 * inc_x + 10 * x + 1 * inc_x '(m) 13233
    x = 0: debug_print 10000 * inc_x + 1000 * x + 100 * inc_x + 10 * x + 1 * inc_x '(n) 11223
End Sub

Function inc_x()
    x = x + 1
    inc_x = x
End Function

Function debug_print(msg)
    Debug.Print msg
End Function
```

Comment: I can't explain (h) but why do you think c, d and g should print 1? In every case you are in effect doing 1+1.

Comment: @SJR Thank you for asking. I first thought that the left side of the + operator is evaluated before the right side, and that will explain why a,b,e, and f prints 2.( inc_x on the left is evaluated before the x on the right)

Comment: @SJR However c, d, and g seem to be not following that rule because if x on the left side is evaluated before the inc_x on the right is evaluated, that x on the left should become 0 as initialized in the first statement of each lines. After the left x becomes 0, inc_x on the right will be evaluated which becomes 1. The result of that expression for c and d will be 0+1, and the g should be 0+0+1. This is why I thought c, d, and g should print 1.

Comment: You can see what's going on by stepping through and observing the locals window. In (c) `x + inc_x`, yes `x` is initially zero but then the function increases it by 1, and `x` is global.

Comment: @SJR So are you saying that inc_x should be evaluated before x regardless of which one is on the left or right? That seems to be true for (a)-(g) so  I think you are correct. Still, I feel the strangeness because of (h) and also why left/right is not considered for the ordering of the evaluation.

Comment: Actually now I'm not sure. You haven't declared any variable types and if you declare them as `Long` (d) changes to 1.

Comment: @SJR Wow ! I did not know that! Thank you for the experiment. I will try myself after I go back home. I was also planning to try "100*inc_x + 10*x + 1*inc_x". I assume it will be 123 but let us see...

Comment: @SJR I added the results of the experiments in the question. Thank you again for all the comments !

Comment: Interesting one, don't really know what's going on there, quirks of the Excel engine I guess.